# SpringBoot Config Server file separator issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

I have configued Spring Boot Config server (2.4.1 version) integrated with Git repository.

Config looks valid, there is no issue during loading files from git, however when i point to
localhoast:port/application/dev
i get

```
{"name":"application","profiles":["dev"],"label":null,"version":"7e67e69e075b05d9fa50e3255deef7585ed658c7","state":null,"propertySources":[]}
```

I turned on logging everything and I discovered, that config server downloaded file correctly and saved file somewhere in temp folder like:

```
  (1)  C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/config-repo-5493381163789847226/
```

however NativeEnironmentRepository is expecting that it will be in:

```
(2)   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\config-repo-5493381163789847226\
```

which is also valid windows path.

When I turn on debuggin I found out that
NativeEnvironmentRepository check path   (1)

against pattern (2) and it fails. So in result

```
"propertySources":[]
```

is empty.

Is this a bug on SpringBoot config server? or should I setup/change something in configuration?
It looks like NativeEnvironmentRepository should use system File.separator...

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with spring boot 2.4.1 in windows platform. It is solved by spring 2.4.2.snapshot.
Spring 2.4.1 worked properly in linux ubuntu. I dont know what is the problem.